# strongswan ikev2 connect to the same server

Tags: vpn, strongswan, ikev2

I have a strongswan ikev2 vpn installed on my server.
With my win10 laptop I can connect to the vpn and and connect to everything via vpn.

But how can I connect to my server? I have a service on a blocked port on my server so I am using this vpn. Connecting to a differend server with this port works but not for my own.

I saw somewhere that you, if you have more than one ip, you can set somewhere in your server this ip to connect to it. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you mean in your last paragraph. But yes, Windows VPN clients won't tunnel traffic to the VPN server's IP address via VPN.

So you have to assign a second IP address to your server (if that's not already the case) and then connect to that IP address after the VPN tunnel is established to access the server via VPN. The IP address could be from a private range (as long as it doesn't conflict with the subnets the clients are connected to) and installed on any interface (e.g. `lo`).

If you don't want to use IP addresses directly, you could simplify accessing the server by assigning the VPN clients your own DNS server (likely running directly on the second IP address on your server) that resolves the server's domain name to that second IP address.